# Set a property of an existing Wikidata object

Tags: wikidata

[Wikidata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikidata) is a collection of objects that have properties.

e.g. The object [Barcelona](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1492) has a 
["coordinate location" property](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property%3aP625) with value "*41°22'57"N, 2°10'37"E*".

Let's say the property is not set yet. How can I set it programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Pywikibot](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata%3aCreating_a_bot) compat framework:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8  -*-

# Set the Wikivoyage banner of a destination on Wikidata.

import pywikibot

print "Defining data source"
site = pywikibot.Site("en", "wikivoyage")
page = pywikibot.Page(site, u"Asahikawa")
data = pywikibot.DataPage(page)

print "Loading data"
dictionary = data.get()

print "Setting Wikivoyage banner"
data.editclaim(948, u"Kaguraoka Park (Asahikawa) banner.jpg")
print "Banner has been set"
```

Another option could be to directly use the [action=wbcreateclaim](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aWikibase/API#wbcreateclaim) part of the [Wikidata API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php).

Comment: It should be possible to attack this with the api itself given your IP / User / Bot have to needed writing right. Sidenote: I study Linguistic in INALCO & 've been wikipedian for years. I love your AnkiDroid.